# Change file in project when git commit with specified message

Tags: git, bash, commit, githooks, pre-commit-hook

What is best way to provide that some of the git hooks change file in project when i make commit with specified message? 
For example, when i do `$git commit -m "MODIFY"` i want to hook's script modify my file in a certain way. Modification of file is not problem. Problem is how to make git hook to recognize specific message as trigger for modification.

Comment: Is the file you want to modify tracked by git? I think it could or should only be done if the file *isn't* tracked by git.

Comment: @AleksandarDimitrov It should be tracked...

Comment: Is there a variable which temporary store commit message? pre-commit hook's script executes before the commit is actually made, so message should exist somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `post-commit` hook.

https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

> After the entire commit process is completed, the post-commit hook
>   runs. It doesn’t take any parameters, but you can easily get the last
>   commit by running git log -1 HEAD. Generally, this script is used for
>   notification or something similar.

Below is a sample that can be placed in `.git/hooks/post-commit`. And make sure to make this an executable file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running post-commit hook
git log -1 --pretty=oneline HEAD | grep "MODIFY" && touch somefile.txt
```

You could fetch the last commit message via `log -1 HEAD` & pass it through grep to match a pattern

Comment: In hooks folder i see only these files: `applypatch-msg.sample  pre-applypatch.sample      pre-push.sample
commit-msg.sample      pre-commit.sample          pre-rebase.sample
post-update.sample     prepare-commit-msg.sample  update.sample`

Comment: Create a new file with the name `post-commit`